# Tab Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Angularjs and Bootstrap tab here my code:

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">      
      <label>Category</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="product.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories"></select>

      <br/><br />

      <label>Attribute</label>
      <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="attr in product.category.templateAttribute" heading="{{attr.attribute}}">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control" value="{{attr.attribute}}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="name" ng-model="product.attributes[$index].name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="additional price" ng-model="product.attributes[$index].additionalPrice" />
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addItem(product.category.templateAttribute, attr)">
                    add
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                  <input class="form-control" type="file" class="form-control" ng-model="product.attributes[$index].file"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my JS

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap']);

(function(MyApp) {
  'use strict';
  MyApp.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // categories
    $scope.categories = [
      {
        name:'custom', 
        templateAttribute: [
          {attribute: 'material'},
          {attribute: 'soles'},
          {attribute: 'size'}
        ]
      }
    ]; 

    // products
    $scope.products = [
    {
      name: 'custom',
      category: {
        name:'custom', 
        templateAttribute: [
          {
            type: "string",
            attribute: "material"
          },
          {
            type: "string",
            attribute: "soles"
          },
          {
            type: "string",
            attribute: "size"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ];

  // add menu item   
  $scope.addItem = function(list, item){
    list.push(angular.copy(item));
    item = {};
  };

  // remove menu item
  $scope.removeItem = function(list, index){
    list.splice(index ,1);
  };

  }]);
})(angular.module('MyApp'));
```

For example when I click add button at the size tab, it will open a new form in the bottom form, here my first problem, when I click add button at the size tab, the tab and new form is created.

[Live Demo with Complete Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMoxgL)

Wht I did to fix my code? Thank before

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem and what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @jbrown For example issue, when I fill form at the size tab and I want to add new size form, I only click button add and It will show new size form at the bottom size form not make new tab size

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis For example issue, when I fill form at the size tab and I want to add new size form, I only click button add and It will show just new size form at the bottom size form, no make new size tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was wrong. Since you wanted to have many elements inside an attribute, you should put a collection in each attribute and iterate over it.

I have edited your example. Here is a working [solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwpoYO).

All you need is a simple object like that:

```
$scope.categories = [{
      name: 'custom',
      templateAttribute: [{
        attribute: 'material',
        type: "string",
        elements: []
      }, {
        attribute: 'soles',
        type: "string",
        elements: []
      }, {
        attribute: 'size',
        type: "string",
        elements: []
      }]
    }];
```

and in your view you should do something like this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="attr in product.category.templateAttribute" heading="{{attr.attribute}}">

          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addItem(attr)">
            add
          </button>

          <!-- THIS IS THE CRUCIAL PART -->
          <div ng-repeat="element in attr.elements">
            <table class="table">
              <tbody>

              <!-- ------------------ -->
              <!-- PUT HERE YOUR FORM -->
              <!-- ------------------ -->

              </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="removeItem(attr.elements, $index)">
                      remove
            </button>
            <hr />
          </div>

          <br />
          <pre>{{attr|json}}</pre>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very appreciate your help